# How to access drop down in application using applescript?

Tags: applescript, automator, application-loader

I'm trying to tell applescript to open the app, Application Loader, and choose from the drop down list that's in the window. The item that should be chosen will always be the very first item. How do i do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Wow I finally got it working! I pretty much got mad at my script so I just put a random ASCII number and it magically worked. I got pretty happy aha :)

```
activate application "Application Loader"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Application Loader"
        tell the first combo box of window 1
            delay 3
            keystroke (ASCII character 30)
            keystroke (ASCII character 12)
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I'd like to see more of how your finished product turned out.