# Apple Application loader console

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, app-store, application-loader

Is there a command line console for Apple's "Application Loader"?

i would like to automate the whole upload process.

Thank you!

Comment: No. And also why to automate it? Its just a "browse" and "next" action event only right?

Comment: we have about 20 apps, all based on the same code. I need to create a deployment system which builds and uploads/updates those apps without human intervention. This can save us precious time.

Comment: Have you found a proper solution for your task yet?

Comment: "Why automate" hah! I have 96 apps to upload and I have to do it twice because my client filled in the forms and got them wrong, in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

This answer: [How to access drop down in application using applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034038/how-to-access-drop-down-in-application-using-applescript) , may suggest a way to develop an Automator script for the Application Loader.  You could then launch the automator script from the command-line.  Perhaps even build the automator scripts using perl or python, et.al., before running them.

Answer (score 0):

There is XML Feed Support which will likely do what you're looking for.

See WWDC 2012 Session 402.

Comment: I think you meant session 305. But this only covers metadata, not application binaries (.ipa).